# Keeping current user object in memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory, mvp

In a `WinForms` application I want to keep the currently logged user in memory through out the applications life. So that in subsequent user actions I could check the permission against the user. Another option is to store the user information in a text file locally but it seems not safe.

**User Log In verification code**

```
private void ValidateUser()
{
    var hashEntered = Encryption.GetHash(_View.UserID, _View.Password); //hash of the salted password entered by user.

    var User = _DataService.GetUser(_View.UserID); //user trying to log in

    if (user != null)
    {
        var hashInDB = user.PassWord;

        if (hashEntered != hashInDB)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
        }
        else
        {
            _MainView.show(); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name");
    }
}
```

So for the MainView, the currently logged user should be available.

How to keep the current user object in memory until the program exits?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to save the user object and then check permissions against this object. What happens when the users permissions are changed in the backend? This is a classic example of 'Time of check to time of use' problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: I should have mentioned that permission information want be keept in memory. Only the user information (at least UserID)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a singleton.

```
public class UserSession{
    private static volatile User currentUser;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private UserSession() {}

    public static User GetUser(){
        if (currentUser == null) throw new Exception("Not logged in.");
        return currentUser;
    }

    public static void Login(User user){
        if (currentUser != null) throw new Exception("Already logged in");
        lock(syncRoot){
            currentUser = user;
        }
    }

    public static void Logout(){
        lock(syncRoot){
            currentUser = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `lock`, you should `lock` all references to `currentUser`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the user data in `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` of type `IPrincipal` which also has a property called `Identity` (which is of type `IIdentity`). The difference between those two is that you just store security associated data of user (suppose permission or roles ) in principal and other data in Identity. you can use Microsoft's already existing implementation of those two interfaces or you can build them by your own. here is an example

```
class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            // check user for appropriate roles
            return false;
        }
}

class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name); }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomIdentity identity = new CustomIdentity
        {
            UserId = 1,
            Name = "user1"
        };

        CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal
        {
            Identity = identity,
            Roles = new List<string> { "admin", "superAdmin" }
        };

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    }
}
```

Principal is the part of `ExecutionContext` so it will be copied from thread to thread. so even if you were to start a new thread or task or any asynchronous job that would try to get the `Principal` it would be there

you would use this code than to retrieve the user principal

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as CustomPrincipal
```

and this to get user identity

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as CustomIdentity
```